# Something about "-Wl,-rpath=."

Tags: c, linux, gcc, g++, shared-libraries

I have build a shared library libC.so, and it depends on libA.so and libB.so.
And then I build test.c which using libC.so via the command:

```
gcc test.c -o test -fPIC -I./ -L./ -lC
```

It will output error, could not find some symbols which are in libA.so and libB.so.
I know, tt can be build successufully when I add the flags "-lA -lB".

However I could not understood, why can it build successfully via the following command:

```
gcc test.c -o test -fPIC -I./ -L./ -lC -Wl,-rpath=.
```

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: man ld. ...The -rpath option is also used when locating shared objects which are needed by shared objects explicitly  included  in  the  link;...

Answer (score 0):

I think your libA.so and libB.so are present in the current directory.
Your providing the linking option -Wl -rpath as your current directory.
So your linker takes the libraries in the current directory and link the symbols.

It is not giving any errors because of the linker options you have specified.

The next doubt you might get is,
I have only specified the directories to search but not specified libraries.
How is the linker is taking libA.so and libB.so libraries also?
But the linker is intelligent and it thinks that you have forgot to include these interdependent libraries (You might not know about interdependency)but you have specified the path to search for all the dependent libraries. So it picks the interdependent libraries.

I think it only works for Interdependency only. All direct libraries should be specified with -l option i think.